# Labels vs instruction sequences in registers (SICP)

Tags: scheme, sicp, mit-scheme

In section 5.5.7 of [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-4.html#%25_toc_start) it says

> `External-entry` assumes that the machine is started with `val` containing the location of an instruction sequence that puts a result into `val` and ends with `(goto (reg continue))`.

Later in the section it says

> In order to transform the object code produced by the compiler into executable instructions for the evaluator register machine, we use the procedure `assemble` from the register-machine simulator (section 5.2.2). We then initialize the `val` register to point to the list of instructions, set the `flag` so that the evaluator will go to `external-entry`, and start the evaluator.

The code is shown as:

```
external-entry
  (perform (op initialize-stack))
  (assign env (op get-global-environment))
  (assign continue (label print-result))
  (goto (reg val))

(define (compile-and-go expression)
  (let ((instructions
         (assemble (statements
                    (compile expression 'val 'return))
                   eceval)))
    (set! the-global-environment (setup-environment))
    (set-register-contents! eceval 'val instructions)
    (set-register-contents! eceval 'flag true)
    (start eceval)))
```

Both paragraphs seem to indicate that the value stored in `'val` is a label indicating where to jump for the instructions but the code itself shows them directly setting the contents of a register to a sequence of instructions.

How does this code work? Surely they are not assigning a whole sequence of machine instructions into a single register? The `(goto (reg val))` implies what is stored inside `'val` is a label, so it can't be a sequence of instructions yet the assignment implies it's not.

For reference (all code taken from: https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-4.html#%_toc_start):

```
(define (assemble controller-text machine)
  (extract-labels controller-text
    (lambda (insts labels)
      (update-insts! insts labels machine)
      insts)))

(define (extract-labels text receive)
  (if (null? text)
      (receive '() '())
      (extract-labels (cdr text)
       (lambda (insts labels)
         (let ((next-inst (car text)))
           (if (symbol? next-inst)
               (receive insts
                        (cons (make-label-entry next-inst
                                                insts)
                              labels))
               (receive (cons (make-instruction next-inst)
                              insts)
                        labels)))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that SICP is modeling a register machine not in a low-level language, with memory represented as arrays of cells, and addresses as integers, but in Scheme.

This means that registers, instructions, etc. are all Scheme data structures.

For instance, a sequence of instructions is a list, in particular a list alternating labels and instructions, and similarly a “pointer” to an istruction is simply a variable whose value is a list of instructions (see, for instance, the section on [Test, branch and goto instructions](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-4.html#%_toc_%_sec_Temp_730) in which it is said: “A goto instruction is similar to a branch, except that the destination may be specified either as a label or as a register”).